# RXJS: assigning and then reusing value between operators

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose I have a function `GetUserRecommendedSongs`. It does the following:

1. It presents the user with a dialog: what is your mood today?
   (happy\gloomy\nostalgic)
2. Using the result it calls a service `GetUserRecommendationsByMood`.
3. It then returns a result for example: `{mood: "nostalgic", songIds:
   [12, 25]}`;
4. The caller of this function (possibly several ui components) would
   use the result to play the songs under the title `"so you feel ${result.mood} today?"`

The problem is I use the mood twice: to get the recommendations, and in the final result.

**With `async\await` I would do:**

```
const requiredMood = await ShowRequiredMoodDialog();
//handle cancellation e.g. if(!mood)
let recommendedSongs = await GetUserRecommendations(mood);
return {mood, recommendedSongs};
```

**However with rxjs I was only able to come up with the following:**

```
let mood$ = ShowRequiredMoodDialog().pipe(share) //has to be shared so we don't show the dialog twice
let recommendedSongs$ = mood$.pipe(switchMap((mood)=> GetUserRecommendations(mood)));
return forkJoin(mood$, recommendedSongs$) //with some selector\map to turn into object
```

*(note to reader: don't use this as a reference to rxjs, as I did not test this code)*

This code is quite complicated. Can it be simplified?

Comment: with `rxjs` you can always end up with `async/await` using the `toPromise` method of observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only different way that comes to my mind is like this but I don't know which one is more readable:

```
mood$.pipe(
  switchMap(mood => GetUserRecommendations(mood).pipe(
    map(recommendedSongs => [mood, recommendedSongs]),
  ),
)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is how I've been doing it and I find it cleaner than share-ing.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

```
let mood$ = ShowRequiredMoodDialog().pipe(share());
let recommend = (mood) => {
  return { mood, songs: GetUserRecommendations(mood) };
};
let recommendedSongs$ = mood$.pipe(switchMap(recommend));
return recommendedSongs$;
```